# New to cocoapods - I can't seem to import libraries downloaded with cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

the `pods install` completes successfully, but when I open the workspace, XCode doesn't seem to be autocompleting the .h files' names when I import (also does not compile). As if the files are not there. It will autocomplete if I start to type them in `<....>`, but it still won't compile the new libraries

[image: screenshot (FBShimmering.h)]
<sub>(source: [paulhalp.in](http://paulhalp.in/media/cocoahelp.png))</sub>

Comment: my project isnt finding the .h file

Comment: To recreate this problem: 
1. install latest cocoapods Gem 
2. new XCode project 
3. make a basic podfile in the project directory 
4. run pod install 
5. open the generated workspace 
6. cry when you cant link any libraries / header files

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#import <FBShimmer/FBShimmer.h>
```

You should also get autocomplete with this.

Comment: are there any other steps I've missed after doing `pod install`?

Comment: did you import FBShimmer or FBShimmering from my example?

Comment: yep, didn't work either `#import <FBShimmering/FBShimmering.h>`